# Maven build manifest info config

Tags: java, maven, manifest

My greetings!

I use maven to build my app and I need to change one thing in the build info. MANIFEST.mf contains basic information about the build, for example:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: dev4
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_35
Main-Class: com.*.Main
```

I need to add the information about the current revision of the build, so in the manifest file we could see an added line, something like "Revision: 1000"

Is there any way, so I could configure the properties of info, written to MANIFEST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Build Number Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) for this.

This will set properties you can use in the `archive` configuration parameter of the jar plugin. See [Manifest Customization](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/manifest-customization.html) and [Maven Archiver](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html) for more information about configuring the manifest.

Comment: I've already used and I'm struggling with 
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) on project error
...trying to fix it. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

See `Maven Archiver` for changing Manifest file http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html.